# TabControl clips client area when displaying overflow arrows

Tags: c, winapi, windows-xp, tabcontrol

This bug appears only with common control v6 (theme enabled) on XP (seems to work on 7 and 2008). I wonder if someone else might have seen this <strike>bug</strike> feature.

When you have a single-line TabControl with lots of tabs, a pairs of arrows should appear if there is not enough space to display all the tabs. This is all nice except that the client area is also clipped, which is not nice at all.

Have I miss something ? I played with tabcontrol's window style, but no luck so far.

To illustrate this, it's actually best to see it in action:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND htab, hbut;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE instance,
                    HINSTANCE previnst,
                    LPSTR args,
                    int wndState)
{
    int i;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl = {
        .hInstance = instance, .lpszClassName = L"WindowsApp",
        .lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure, .style = CS_DBLCLKS, .cbSize = sizeof wincl,
        .hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1)
    };

    InitCommonControls();

    wincl.hIcon   = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(L"WindowsApp", L"Windows App", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, instance, NULL);

    htab = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_TABCONTROL,
        L"MyTab", WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 514, 325, hwnd,
        (HMENU) 10, instance, NULL);

    hbut = CreateWindow(
        WC_BUTTON, L"My nice button that is clipped", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
        10, 30, 494, 285, htab, (HMENU) IDOK, instance, NULL
    );

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        WCHAR  myBuf[100];
        TCITEM tc = {.mask = TCIF_TEXT, .pszText = myBuf};
        wsprintf(myBuf, L"My super tab %d", i + 1);
        TabCtrl_InsertItem(htab, i, &tc);
    }

    SendMessage(hbut, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), FALSE);
    SendMessage(htab, WM_SETFONT, (LPARAM) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), FALSE);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, wndState);

    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return messages.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT r;
    switch (message) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
        MoveWindow(htab, 10, 10, r.right-20, r.bottom - 20, TRUE);
        MoveWindow(hbut, 10, 30, r.right-40, r.bottom - 60, TRUE);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't test it (I have Win7) but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298367%28v=VS.85%29.aspx you need to have clip siblings on the tab control and also the parent window. You could also try using the tab control's adjust rect message to get the positions for your button.

Comment: It's even weirder than that: a few more testing and it appears that only push buttons got clipped by this stupid up-down control. I've tested: listview, progress, plain child window, static, editbox, scrollbars. No clipping occurs for these controls.

My workaround so far has been to place buttons as parent of the dialog and place them so that they look as parent of the tab. Small cosmetical problem though: the border around the buttons is drawn with the background brush of the dialog instead of the tab. Oh well...